# Add a password to a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I’m a newbie with everything related to Google Apps Scripts and I’m trying to implement a password with a Prompt that shows every time the document is opened, so every person that tries to access the Google Sheets has to type a password, otherwise they won’t be able to edit it. It kind of works, the thing is that if I (the owner of the document) haven’t unlocked it myself, the prompt won’t show to the other editors. Is this the correct way to do so?

```
  function onOpen() {
  protectSheet();
  password();
}
 
function protectSheet() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 
  //Protect the sheet
  var protection = sheet.protect().setDescription("Only owner can edit");
 
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  protection.addEditor(me);
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  Logger.log(protection.getEditors());
  Logger.log(Session.getEffectiveUser());
 
  if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
    protection.setDomainEdit(false);
  }
}
 
function unprotectSheet() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 
  //Unprotect sheet
  var unprotection = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)[0];
  if (unprotection && unprotection.canEdit()) {
    unprotection.remove();
    Logger.log("Entró: "+unprotection.getEditors());
 
  }
}
 
function password() {
  var password = "123";
  var textoIngresado;
 
  do {
 
    var passwordPrompt = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Protected document", "Type password", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
 
    if (passwordPrompt.getSelectedButton() == SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.CANCEL) {
      protectSheet();
      console.log("CANCELLED, PROTECTED");
 
      break;
 
    } else if (passwordPrompt.getSelectedButton == SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.CLOSE) {
      protectSheet();
      console.log("CLOSED, PROTECTED");
      break;
    }
 
    textoIngresado = passwordPrompt.getResponseText();
 
  }
 
  while (textoIngresado != password);
 
  if (textoIngresado == password) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A7").setValue("Unlocked");
    unprotectSheet();
 
    console.log("UNLOCKED");
 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is using a onOpen simple trigger. It looks that you are missing that simple triggers have limitations (for details see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

Instead of a simple trigger, use an installable trigger (for details see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Regarding using a custom password it looks that you are trying "to discover the hot water". Instead of creating a custom access control system the best is to use the Google Drive sharing system:

1. change the sharing settings i.e. change from editor to viewer.
2. instead of changing the settings by using individual emails you might use a Google Group

Related

- [Google Sheets Appscript pop up prompt response and hide sheets until response is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59925249/1595451)

Comment: Thank for your answer! I changed the simple trigger for an installable trigger and it solved my problem :) It doesn't work like I'd liked to, because if another user tries to enter the Google Sheets and let's say I'm already there, then it's going to be blocked for both of us, but thanks anyways!!!

Comment: @AngélicaCastillo If you are using a Google Workspace account you can get the user email  and use it in a improved algorithm